# Enabled Cookies in webView on Android (CapacitorJS 4)

Tags: android, axios, webview, session-cookies, capacitor

How to enable cookies so that they are automatically installed from the response to the request (axios with withCredentials) and authorization works with them in the future. Android version 12, API 31. I know that cookies are disabled in these versions for security reasons, but I can enable them how to do it. I searched everywhere for information, and what I found didn't help me. The project is outdated and I can't change the authorization method. At the moment I use CapacitorsJS 4 versions. On WEB and iOS it work, but not on android. Help me please.

I tried
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
in MainActivity.java.
I tried send requests from http, https

Answer (score 0):

I understood the solution. axios do not work with a conventional capacitor. You need to use the plugin "CapacitorHttp", then cookies will be automatically set and sent in requests. But "CapacitorHttp" does not automatically understand the type. It loses the "Content-Type", so it must be ензу manually, and also if the server does not receive a json format, but just text, then there will also be an error. It will be necessary to specify on the server which format is given.